# Html select is not respecting margin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, select, margin

Here is a quick example:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6j851yqn/)

[image]

As you can see in the image above, all the labels, tables are aligned to the margin inside th container(green margin) but the select seems to go over it, i see on css it has 15 padding, but the padding is only for the text inside.

```
<%--MODULES--%>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12" id="prueba">
            <div class="row">
                <label class="col-xs-12">Módulos</label>
                <select class="col-xs-12" multiple="multiple" id="cboModulos" name="cboModulos">
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Same thing happens with the textbox in the right, but i bet its the same case.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `.container` div around your content. The `.row` class has negative margins to offset column padding which is causing your elements to be misaligned.

When using a grid system, the grid classes should be applied to block level elements only (inputs are inline, not block). I have refactored your code with grid wrappers around the elements.

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hko1qLf1/)

Comment: the updated fiddle has the same problem , as you can see the label is not aligned to the select

Answer (score 0):

If the only column you want to show inside a `class="row"` is a `class="col-anything-12"` (mind the **12**) in most cases you don't actually need either that `class="row"` or `class="col-xs-12"`.

Other that that don't set the `col-` class on select element directly. Wrap it inside a `div` and add the class to that `div`.